# reactjs app showing 404 not found in nginx server

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, nestjs

I uploaded react.js application to server. I'm using nginx server. I'm trying the develop and prod servers right now. but i am getting 404 error.

**this server.conf file**

docker/nginx/server.conf in the directory

```
server {

  listen 80;

  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html index.html;
  }

  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }

}
```

**in my Dockerfile like this**

```
FROM node:14.18.3-alpine3.15 as builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . ./
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./docker/nginx/server.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

how can I solve this?

thank you

Comment: where is the server name ?

Comment: I didn't add the server name.I set port 80 in develop and prod server. do I have to add the server name?

Comment: The server name is the website address for ex - www.example.com. So when someone tries this URL it will hit your IP and port 80. otherwise, how will Nginx know www.example.com should go this server block.

Comment: @RanuVijay When there's no `server`, it should serve the files no matter what host is specified in the request.

Comment: Just to make sure that you have the files you expect in the image, can you run `docker run --rm <image name> ls -al /usr/share/nginx/html`?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if this works?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

The above first attempts to serve request as file, then as a directory, and then redirects to index(react) if no file found.

Also, it is recommended to copy the `server.conf` to `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` instead of `conf.d` directory.

Comment: How will your Nginx understand which URL to forward to this server block ??

Comment: In this configuration, nginx routes the requests to the default server for port 80 (the only server block). So, server_name can be empty or not defined at all.

Comment: hello, i tried but it didn't work.I tried the old way again.I guess it doesn't see index.html